# How on form saving fresh header button hidden condition?

Tags: filamentphp

In laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 app I use status selection input with several options and depending on current status button in
getHeaderActions() I need to show/hide button, which opens modal dialog to make an action on the current row.

Problem is that when in status selection input I select other option(with that option button must be opened) and click "Save changes"
on saving data :
a) this button is not visible
b) "updated_at" field is not updated

I try to use refreshFormData in afterSave method:

```
class EditUserQuizRequest extends EditRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = UserQuizRequestResource::class;

    protected function afterSave(): array
    {
        \Log::info(varDump($this->record, ' -10 afterSave UNDER UPP $this->record::')); // I see valid data of the form
        $this->refreshFormData([
            'updated_at', // this field is updated, but with non formatted value


            // If to comment row above and uncomment row belowm - updated_atis not changed
//            'updated_at'=> DateConv::getFormattedDateTime($this->record->updated_at, \App\Enums\DatetimeOutputFormat::AS_TEXT),


            // that is the action button I need to show when status changed and saving - but it does not work
            'Appoint User Meeting'
        ]);

        return $this->record->toArray();
    }

    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {

        return [
            Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
            Action::make('Appoint User Meeting')
                // If "Needs for managers review" selected, then meeting can be appointed with user by "Create User Meeting" button.
                ->hidden($this->record->getAttribute('status') !== UserQuizRequest::STATUS_ACCEPT_FOR_MEETING)
                // Condtion above works ok when page is reloaded, but not after form is saved
                ->steps([
                ...
```

But if I refresh browser's page with F5, I see 'Appoint User Meeting' button visible and 'updated_at' with valid data...
How to fix this issue ?

**Additive info :**

updated_at is not  a datepicker , that is TextInput, defined :

```
TextInput::make('updated_at')
    ->afterStateHydrated(function (TextInput $component, $state) {
        $userQuizRequestModel = $component->getModelInstance();
        $component->state(DateConv::getFormattedDateTime(
            $userQuizRequestModel->getAttribute('updated_at'),
            \App\Enums\DatetimeOutputFormat::AS_TEXT) . ' - ' . DateConv::getFormattedDateTime(
            $userQuizRequestModel->getAttribute('updated_at'),
            \App\Enums\DatetimeOutputFormat::AGO_FORMAT)
        );
    })->disabled()
    ->hidden(fn(?UserQuizRequest $record
    ) => ($record === null or $record->getAttribute('updated_at') === null))
    ->label('Updated at')->label('updated_at 1'),
```

so I can not apply displayFormat to it, as only datetimepicker has displayFormat .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to a)**

Filament caches the header actions, they don't mention anything in their docs, so for now to fix this problem you can add the following lines to the afterSave:

```
$this->cachedHeaderActions = [];
$this->cacheHeaderActions();
```

**Answer to b)**

The `afterStateHydrated` only works when the `$form->fill` is called and that doesn't happen on update. Maybe it's a bug, so you could report an issue to the Github repo.

An option to fix it would be to apply to following line in `afterSave()`, instead of the `refreshFormData`:

```
$this->form->fill($this->record->toArray())
```

p.s. there is also a formatStateUsing, as a shorthand for the `afterStateHydrated`.

And a Placeholder works out of the box with a content, this is what's also used in the Filament demo for created_at and updated_at, see: https://github.com/filamentphp/demo/blob/main/app/Filament/Resources/Shop/CategoryResource.php

Comment: Yes, cachedHeaderActions works ok.
Any idea how to update updated_at field with formatted value I mentioned in my topic ?

Comment: How does your updated_at field look? When you have a DateTimePicker you can use `displayFormat`. When you have a Placeholder you can use `content`. And when you have a TextInput, maybe it's possible with a mask? but not sure

Comment: Pls, read Additive info

Comment: @mstdmstd see updated answer